# On menu clicked --> animate & scroll to the element dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a navigation menu: Intro, Size, Play, Food. When a user click on the hyper link of the menu item, I want to navigate to that element and animate.

For example, if a user click on the **Size** menu item, then I want to animate  & scroll down to the item with `id="Size"`.

Note: *Here **size** menu item href does not have any value, because it is a dynamic.*

index.html

```
<nav>
    <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Intro</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Size</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Play</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Food</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</nav>

<aside id="Size" class="sidebar">
        <h3>Size</h3>
        <img src="Images/boxer2.jpg" />
        <p>Hegyét bár érti szeret.
        </p>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform smooth scrolling using `$.animate(...)` by passing the offset position of the element to `scrollTop`.

**$.animate:**http://api.jquery.com/animate/

**HTML CODE:**

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Intro</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Size</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Play</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Food</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
</nav>
<aside id="Intro" class="sidebar">
    <h3>Intro</h3>
    <img src="Images/boxer2.jpg" />
    <p>Hegyét bár érti szeret.</p>
</aside>
<aside id="Size" class="sidebar">
    <h3>Size</h3>
    <img src="Images/boxer2.jpg" />
    <p>Hegyét bár érti szeret.</p>
</aside>
<aside id="Play" class="sidebar">
    <h3>Play</h3>
    <img src="Images/boxer2.jpg" />
    <p>Hegyét bár érti szeret.</p>
</aside>
<aside id="Food" class="sidebar">
    <h3>Food</h3>
    <img src="Images/boxer2.jpg" />
    <p>Hegyét bár érti szeret.</p>
</aside>
```

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
$('li a').on('click', function (e) {
   var targetSec = $(this).text();
   $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#' + targetSec).offset().top
   }, 2000);
});
```

**LIVE DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/3Xm48/11/

Happy Coding:)

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to do something like this

```
$("nav ul li").click(function() {
    var liText = $(this).text();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + liText ).offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```